# Zend form and input button

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to add button input to the form element. I'd like the rendered code to be `<input type="button" ...">` I tried setting attribs field like so:

```
$this->addElement('submit', 'cancel', array(
                'ignore' => true,
                'label' => 'Anuluj',
                'attribs'=>array('class' => 'class_name', 'type' => 'button')  )
        );
```

but i still got `<input type="submit" ...">` instead `<input type="button" ...">`

Setting class attribute works, but setting the type doesn't. Any Idea to get type="button"?

Answer (score 2):

Use `button` as the first parameter instead, which will give you a `<button>` HTML element instead (functionally the same as `<input type="button" ..>`).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for button

```
    $this->addElement('button', 'submitted');
    $submitElement = $this->getElement('submitted');
    $submitElement->setAttrib('class',"btn-primary btn");
    $submitElement->setAttrib('value', 'submitted');
    $submitElement->setLabel('SUBMIT');
```

The Html code is,

```
<button name="submitted" id="submitted" type="button" class="btn-primary btn">SUBMIT</button>
```